# Single column HighCharts for an array

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

I am using stacked percentage highcharts. I want only a single column.

```
var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'User Source Chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Users']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total users'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'percent'
                }
            },
   series: [{
            name: 'Referred',
            data: [referred]
        }, {
            name: 'Direct',
            data: [direct]
        },{
            name: 'AIDs',
            data: count
        },]
        };
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

`referred` and `direct` are variables, while `count` is an array. The output that I am getting is, direct and referred are coming in one column but for count array, there is a separate column for each array element. I want all count array elements to be displayed in the same column as direct and referred i.e. there should only be one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description it works fine for me, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/274/

I have set variables:

```
var referred = 13,
    direct = 33,
    count = [25];
```

as random variables.

Comment: Hi, but I don't want this output. I want each array element in the single stacked percentage column. For example, if count=[25,30], two columns are displayed. I want them to be in one single column.

Comment: Logic in Highcharts is different - when you set count =[25,30] it means that you have two points [0,25] and [1,30] and that's haw they would be plotted. If you want to stack them, you need to split count into two series, and set for them the same '`stack`.

Comment: I figured out that it means I have a second point. Still not able to figure out how will I stack them by splitting count into multiple series. Can you please help?

Comment: But this will only work when elements of array are already known. Suppose I want to add a dynamic array i.e I do not know the size of array, then what should I do? I have already tried this-
`options.series.data.push(count[i]);` in a for loop. but this again makes separate columns. I want a single column.

Comment: Just go through your count array and add new series for each entry, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/279/

Comment: Oh, so this is the correct way to do this. Thank you so much for the help :)